# Removing LINQ-To-Objects from C# 3.5 project to convert it to .net 2.0

Tags: c#, linq, .net-2.0, linq-to-objects

Are there any quick way to replace LINQ method calls such as (Concat,SequenceEqual,Skip,Take,......) from a project with their equivalents (such as static methods or any thing else)??

are there any .net-2 library to simulate these methods behavior??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [LINQBridge](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqbridge.aspx) to work around only needing .NET 2, and still having the default LINQ to Objects behavior.

Answer (score 0):

They are quite easy to hack together your self, shouldn't take you many hours if you just use a few of them.

I have some here if you want a start: http://sharpkom.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/sharpkom/ExternalComponents/LinqEx/LinqEx.cs?revision=1566&view=markup